# Chartist.js: divisor doesn't work

Tags: javascript, chartist.js

I'm trying to make my Y axis be divided into [0, 250, 500, 750, 1000] exactly. But the 'divisor' attribute that I've set to 250 does not work and it still remains the default 200.

```
<body>
<div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth" id="myChart"></div>   
</body>

new Chartist.Line(
    '#myChart',
    {
         labels: ['Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 4', 'Week 5'],
         series: [ [560, 600, 840, 900, 400] ]
    }, 
    {divisor: 250}
);
```

See the full code at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm08s3mw/1/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to get what you want:

- Your JSFiddle is using an old version of ChartistJS (0.7.2), upgrade to the latest (0.9.1)
- Specify the type of the scale for the `axisY` as `Chartist.FixedScaleAxis`
- Define the `low` and `high` in the `axisY`
- Define ticks as you would like (in your case `[0, 250, 500, 750, 1000]`)

The final result should look like this:

```
new Chartist.Line('#myChart', {
   labels : [ 'Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 4', 'Week 5' ],
   series : [ {
       name : 'one',
       data : [ 560, 600, 840, 900, 400 ]
   }, {
       name : 'two',
       data : [ 500, 510, 740, 300, 300 ]
    } ]
}, {      
   axisY : {
       type : Chartist.FixedScaleAxis,
       low : 0,
       high : 1000,
       ticks : [ 0, 250, 500, 750, 1000 ]
   },     
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hatemalimam/g4sqzseo/1/)

Comment: Thank you, it worked in my project as well! Can you please help me achieve the same effect with a barChart: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4sqzseo/3/)

Comment: I'm not sure why in JSFiddle it's not working for the bar, your fiddle is 100% correct, even if you test the same code in the examples of the chartist.js site it would work !  See: http://i.imgur.com/gPyxblV.png?1

Comment: This should be mentioned in the documentation